# Django ORM: How I can count weekends between two dates

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

How I can count Saturdays and Sundays between two dates using Djang ORM?

i.e

```py
Article.objects.annotate(days_to_post_duration=Case(
    When(
        days_to_post__isnull=False,
        then=F('days_to_post') * timezone.timedelta(days=1)
    ),
    default=timezone.timedelta(days=DEFAULT_DAYS_TO_POST),
    output_field=models.DurationField()
)
).annotate(
    due_date=models.ExpressionWrapper(
        F('approved_at') + F('days_to_post_duration'),
        output_field=models.DateTimeField()
    ),
    due_date_duration=models.ExpressionWrapper(
        F('due_date') - timezone.now(),
        output_field=models.DurationField()
    ),
    due_days_=Extract('due_date_duration', 'days'),
)
```

I want to skip weekends from due date and count only working days in due date. For example, if article approved on Friday and days_to_post is 3 then instead of getting due date next week's Monday I want to skip weekend (Saturday and Sunday) and due date should be next week's Wednesday.

Above code also include weekends in due date. I want to count weekends and increase day_to_post accordingly.

Comment: Is the `approved_at` always a work day?

Comment: No, it is a DateTime field. It can be any date.

Comment: sure, but it is not because it can, that it *will*... It is possible you added a validator for example that said that `approved_at` is always a weekday...

Comment: It is mostly a weekday but our team can work on weekends. We need to handle all the cases. You can add Case When conditions that if approved_at is not a weekday then add one or two days in approve_at date.

Comment: Your requirement seems to be self contradicting. You want to remove weekends but your team may work on weekends and you must handle all cases. You cannot do that given those facts. So what are you actually trying to accomplish in a business since.

Answer (score 0):

here's a solution using `relativedelta` module from `dateutil` to get the due date with skipping weekends

```py
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta, MO, TU, WE, TH, FR
from datetime import date
def get_due_date(start_date, days_to_due):
    due_date = start_date
    while days_to_due > 0:
        if due_date.weekday() <= 4: # Mon-Fri
            due_date += relativedelta(days=+1)
        else:
            # Skip weekend by moving to next Monday
            due_date += relativedelta(weekday=MO)
        days_to_due -= 1
    return due_date
# Usage
start_date = date(2023, 7, 7) # Friday 
days_to_due = 3
due_date = get_due_date(start_date, days_to_due)
print(due_date) # 2023-07-11 (TU)
```

another solution using Django ORM

```py
from django.db.models import Count, Case, When
start_date = # type start date here
end_date = # type end date here
Article.objects.filter(
    date__range=(start_date, end_date)
).annotate(
    is_weekend=Case(
        When(date__week_day=5, then=True), # Saturday
        When(date__week_day=6, then=True), # Sunday
        default=False,
        output_field=models.BooleanField()
    )
).filter(is_weekend=True).aggregate(
    weekend_days=Count('id')
)
```

Ref:
[relativedelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html)